# Error to compile qwtpolar et qwtplot3d with msvc 2010

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qwtpolar

What I want to do : Compile qt-everywhere_opensource-4.7.3, qwt, qtwtplot3d and qwtpolar with msvc 2010 or higher.

what I do :

1. Install Visual Studio C++ Express 2010
2. Download the code source file “qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3 “
3. Extract the content of the zip in the “C:\Qt\static”
     a.Be careful to change the name of directories. They have to be short without space.
4. Creation of the environment Variables
      a.QMAKESPEC : win32-msvc2010
      b.QTDIR : C:\Qt\static
     c.Path :
5. %QTDIR%\bin\
6. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin 3.Modification of the directory number 2 to delate space and brackets  become  C:\Cpp\VC\bin\
7. Open Visual Studio C++ command
8. Go in to the QTDIR directories : cd %QTDIR%
9. Starts with the commands configure & nmake in this directory

Compile qwt, qwtpolar, qwtplot3D

1. open visual studio command prompt
2. move into qwt directory :

   a.qmake

   b.nmake
3. move into qwtpolar  :: error

   a.qmake
     b.nmake
4. move into qwtplot3D ::error

   a.qmake

   b.nmake

But the mistake appear: 
C:..\qwt_polar_item.h(13) : fatal error C1083 : impossible d’ouvrir le fichier include : ‘qwt_text.h’ :No such file directory qwt_polar_plot.cpp
…Many errors like that..
Génération de code en cours..
NMAKE : fatal error U1077 : ‘echo » : code retour ‘0x2’
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077 : ‘C:\Cpp\VC\BIN\nmake.exe’ : code retour ‘Ox2’
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077 : ‘cd’ : code retour ‘0x2’
Stop

Compilation of qt and qwt is successfull.

But impossilble to compile qwtpolar and qwtplot3d with msvc 2010. 
Nmake fatal error code return '0x2'
Why this mistake appear? how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Qwt first ( make install ).

Next you have to configure qmake so, that it can find qwt.prf to make "CONFIG += qwt" working.

Detail can be found in the INSTAll notes of qwtpolar.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I built for first time qt with configure & nmake with the cmd prompt of MSVC 2010 express.
After that I built qwt : qmake & nmake (I didn't try the cmd make install).
When I try to start : qmake & nmake in the qwtpolar or qwtplot3D directory I have this mistake.
When I open qwt.prf there is no "CONFIG += qwt", I have to add it ? but where in this file ?